# Unable to mount and burn DVD on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: mount, dvd

Whenever I try to mount and burn a DVD on my drive I receive this error message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sr0 at /media/nnnok/Vidyarambh:
Command-line `mount -t "iso9660" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500" "/dev/sr0" "/media/nnnok/Vidyarambh"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0
```

What is the cause of this error and what potential solutions are there to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected

You're trying to burn to a DVD that's write protected. Perhaps it's already burned and a DVD-/+R?